# Generating combinations with recursion and skipping or deleting items

Tags: python

I have array of tuples in python like this:

```
[(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4)]
```

I need to generate all combinations of given length, but with some condition.There should be always only 2 same numbers in tuple.

For this example, when starting generating combination, I need to add `(1,2)` then `(2,3)` but then I cannot add `(2,4)`, because number `2` is already used 2 times in `[(1,2),(2,3)]` so I need to skip or delete of start array these items (which contains number 2): `(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,2)` and continue with generating. First combination of given length 3 will be `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)]`, second `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]` and then `[(1,2),(2,4),(3,1)]` and so on.

Can someone help me how to do that ?

Comment: Can you provide sample outputs for combinations of length 2 for the input provided>

Comment: Yes: `[(1,2),(2,3)]`, `[(1,2),(2,4)]`, `[(1,2),(2,5)]`, `[(1,2),(2,6)]`, `[(1,2),(3,1)]`, `[(1,2),(3,2)]` , `[(1,2),(3,4)]`, `[(2,3),(2,4)]`, `[(2,3),(2,5)]` and so on...

Comment: SO what is it you have skipped here? (1,2),(2.2)?

Comment: I have no `(2,2)` in my array, there will never be 2 same numbers in tuple. When generating pair, nothing will be skipped, because condition, that the number in tuple is used 2 times is true.

Comment: So what elements are you skipping then? I did not get that

Comment: When generating pairs, no elements are skipped.

Comment: then what is the condition `There should be always only 2 same numbers in tuple`? How is that different from normal combinations?

Comment: When you generate triples, the result cannot be `[(1,2),(2,3),(2,4)]`, because number 2 is in tuples used 3 times and condition is 2 times.

Comment: Got it! Let me try something!

Comment: Okay I have tried to write something up for your case! Check the output and see if it is what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
from collections import Counter
def groups(d, l, c = []):
  if l == len(c):
    yield c
  else:
    for i in d:
      if i not in c:
        _c = Counter([j for k in [*c, i] for j in k])
        if all(j < 3 for j in _c.values()):
           yield from groups(d, l, c+[i])

data = [(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4)]
result = list(groups(data, 3))
final_result = [a for i, a in enumerate(result) if all(any(c not in h for c in a) for h in result[:i])]
```

Output:

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)], [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1)], [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 4)], [(1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 1)], [(1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 4)], [(1, 2), (2, 6), (3, 1)], [(1, 2), (2, 6), (3, 4)], [(1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2)], [(1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 4)], [(1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 4)], [(2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1)], [(2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)], [(2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 1)], [(2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4)], [(2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 1)], [(2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 4)], [(2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1)], [(2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4)], [(2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 1)], [(2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 4)], [(2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2)], [(2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4)], [(2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 4)], [(2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1)], [(2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4)], [(2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2)], [(2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 4)], [(2, 5), (3, 2), (3, 4)], [(2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2)], [(2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 4)], [(2, 6), (3, 2), (3, 4)]]
```

Comment: Good solution, but there is 1 problem. There are duplicate arrays, such as `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)]` and `[(2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)]`. Is there a way, how to skip them ?

Comment: It works, but I need to catch duplicates in process of generating combinations, not filter them after generation, because in my real app I am working with array of size 50 and in this case it will take a lot of time. Is there a way how to catch duplicated in `groups` method while generating combinations ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import sample

# Define variables

# All possible elements
all_elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

# Current possible free elements
possible_elements = {e: 0 for e in all_elements}

# Max number of element usage
MAX = 2

# Result length
N = 5

# Tuple length
L = 2

# Result
result = []

for _ in range(N):
    # Check if we can't construct a new tuple
    try:
        # Randomly get free elements
        t = sample(possible_elements.keys(), L)
    except ValueError:
        break
    # Add tuple to result
    result.append(t)
    # Check elements
    for element in t:
        # List for delete non-free elements
        elements_to_delete = []
        # Check if we can't use the element (it is filled to MAX)
        possible_elements[element] += 1
        if possible_elements[element] == MAX:
            # If yes, add it to to-delete list
            elements_to_delete.append(element)
        # Delete all non-free elements
        for e in elements_to_delete:
            del possible_elements[e]
result
```

Returns:

`[[1, 6], [6, 4], [3, 5], [1, 3], [7, 5]]`

Comment: The result is ok, but I need to generate all combinations, not only one random.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this (most of them more efficient), but as long as your original array of tuples is so short, I think you should stick to  the conceptionally easiest way. That may be to create all permutations in 3 for loops (take i, j, k from your array of tuples) (use an if condition to check that i, j and k are not identical) and store this in a dictionary (the key might be the _ separated indices from your array). 
Last you check whether your dictionary has any forbidden combinations (2 is used...) and delete them.
Of course you can also combine the last two steps, but if your original array were to be a LOT longer, this would be slower.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but in my real app I am working with array of length 50 and in this case it will be not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I start with generating an iterator for permutations of length 3 over the tuples using [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).
Then I count all the frequencies for each tuple in the sublist of 3 tuples via [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and if the frequency of an element goes above 2, I do not add that sublist to the final list.

```
import itertools as it
from collections import Counter

li = [(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4)]
perms = []

#Generate all permutations of length 3
for l in it.permutations(li, 3):
    flag = True
    counters = Counter()
    #Iterate through tuple and calculate frequency of each digit via Counter
    #Summing up counters for each tuple
    for tup in l:
        c = Counter(tup)
        counters += c
    #Iterate through the frequency dict, and if a value is above 2, don't add that tuple
    for v in dict(counters).values():
        if v > 2:
            flag = False
    if flag:
        perms.append(l)

print(perms)
```

The output will look like

```
[((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)), ((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1)), ((1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 1)), ((1, 2), (2, 5), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (2, 6), (3, 1)), ((1, 2), (2, 6), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3)), ((1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 5)), ((1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 6)), ((1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2)), ((1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 1)), ((1, 2), (3, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 3)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 5)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 6)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 1)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 2)), ((2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)), ((2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 4)), ((2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1)), ((2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)), ((2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 1)), ((2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4)), ((2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 1)), ((2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 4)), ((2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 2)), ((2, 3), (3, 1), (2, 4)), ((2, 3), (3, 1), (2, 5)), ((2, 3), (3, 1), (2, 6)), ((2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 2)), ((2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 4)), ((2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 5)), ((2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 6)), ((2, 4), (1, 2), (3, 1)), ((2, 4), (1, 2), (3, 4)), ((2, 4), (2, 3), (3, 1)), ((2, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4)), ((2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1)), ((2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4)), ((2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 1)), ((2, 4), (2, 6), (3, 4)), ((2, 4), (3, 1), (1, 2)), ((2, 4), (3, 1), (2, 3)), ((2, 4), (3, 1), (2, 5)), ((2, 4), (3, 1), (2, 6)), ((2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2)), ((2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4)), ((2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 1)), ((2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 4)), ((2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 2)), ((2, 4), (3, 4), (2, 3)), ((2, 4), (3, 4), (2, 5)), ((2, 4), (3, 4), (2, 6)), ((2, 4), (3, 4), (3, 1)), ((2, 4), (3, 4), (3, 2)), ((2, 5), (1, 2), (3, 1)), ((2, 5), (1, 2), (3, 4)), ((2, 5), (2, 3), (3, 1)), ((2, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4)), ((2, 5), (2, 4), (3, 1)), ((2, 5), (2, 4), (3, 4)), ((2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1)), ((2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4)), ((2, 5), (3, 1), (1, 2)), ((2, 5), (3, 1), (2, 3)), ((2, 5), (3, 1), (2, 4)), ((2, 5), (3, 1), (2, 6)), ((2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2)), ((2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 4)), ((2, 5), (3, 2), (3, 1)), ((2, 5), (3, 2), (3, 4)), ((2, 5), (3, 4), (1, 2)), ((2, 5), (3, 4), (2, 3)), ((2, 5), (3, 4), (2, 4)), ((2, 5), (3, 4), (2, 6)), ((2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 1)), ((2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 2)), ((2, 6), (1, 2), (3, 1)), ((2, 6), (1, 2), (3, 4)), ((2, 6), (2, 3), (3, 1)), ((2, 6), (2, 3), (3, 4)), ((2, 6), (2, 4), (3, 1)), ((2, 6), (2, 4), (3, 4)), ((2, 6), (2, 5), (3, 1)), ((2, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)), ((2, 6), (3, 1), (1, 2)), ((2, 6), (3, 1), (2, 3)), ((2, 6), (3, 1), (2, 4)), ((2, 6), (3, 1), (2, 5)), ((2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2)), ((2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 4)), ((2, 6), (3, 2), (3, 1)), ((2, 6), (3, 2), (3, 4)), ((2, 6), (3, 4), (1, 2)), ((2, 6), (3, 4), (2, 3)), ((2, 6), (3, 4), (2, 4)), ((2, 6), (3, 4), (2, 5)), ((2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 1)), ((2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 2)), ((3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)), ((3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4)), ((3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 5)), ((3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 6)), ((3, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2)), ((3, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4)), ((3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2)), ((3, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4)), ((3, 1), (2, 3), (2, 5)), ((3, 1), (2, 3), (2, 6)), ((3, 1), (2, 4), (1, 2)), ((3, 1), (2, 4), (2, 3)), ((3, 1), (2, 4), (2, 5)), ((3, 1), (2, 4), (2, 6)), ((3, 1), (2, 4), (3, 2)), ((3, 1), (2, 4), (3, 4)), ((3, 1), (2, 5), (1, 2)), ((3, 1), (2, 5), (2, 3)), ((3, 1), (2, 5), (2, 4)), ((3, 1), (2, 5), (2, 6)), ((3, 1), (2, 5), (3, 2)), ((3, 1), (2, 5), (3, 4)), ((3, 1), (2, 6), (1, 2)), ((3, 1), (2, 6), (2, 3)), ((3, 1), (2, 6), (2, 4)), ((3, 1), (2, 6), (2, 5)), ((3, 1), (2, 6), (3, 2)), ((3, 1), (2, 6), (3, 4)), ((3, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2)), ((3, 1), (3, 2), (2, 4)), ((3, 1), (3, 2), (2, 5)), ((3, 1), (3, 2), (2, 6)), ((3, 1), (3, 4), (1, 2)), ((3, 1), (3, 4), (2, 4)), ((3, 1), (3, 4), (2, 5)), ((3, 1), (3, 4), (2, 6)), ((3, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1)), ((3, 2), (1, 2), (3, 4)), ((3, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1)), ((3, 2), (2, 4), (3, 4)), ((3, 2), (2, 5), (3, 1)), ((3, 2), (2, 5), (3, 4)), ((3, 2), (2, 6), (3, 1)), ((3, 2), (2, 6), (3, 4)), ((3, 2), (3, 1), (1, 2)), ((3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 4)), ((3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 5)), ((3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 6)), ((3, 2), (3, 4), (1, 2)), ((3, 2), (3, 4), (2, 4)), ((3, 2), (3, 4), (2, 5)), ((3, 2), (3, 4), (2, 6)), ((3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3)), ((3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 4)), ((3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 5)), ((3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 6)), ((3, 4), (1, 2), (3, 1)), ((3, 4), (1, 2), (3, 2)), ((3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2)), ((3, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)), ((3, 4), (2, 3), (2, 5)), ((3, 4), (2, 3), (2, 6)), ((3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 2)), ((3, 4), (2, 4), (2, 3)), ((3, 4), (2, 4), (2, 5)), ((3, 4), (2, 4), (2, 6)), ((3, 4), (2, 4), (3, 1)), ((3, 4), (2, 4), (3, 2)), ((3, 4), (2, 5), (1, 2)), ((3, 4), (2, 5), (2, 3)), ((3, 4), (2, 5), (2, 4)), ((3, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6)), ((3, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1)), ((3, 4), (2, 5), (3, 2)), ((3, 4), (2, 6), (1, 2)), ((3, 4), (2, 6), (2, 3)), ((3, 4), (2, 6), (2, 4)), ((3, 4), (2, 6), (2, 5)), ((3, 4), (2, 6), (3, 1)), ((3, 4), (2, 6), (3, 2)), ((3, 4), (3, 1), (1, 2)), ((3, 4), (3, 1), (2, 4)), ((3, 4), (3, 1), (2, 5)), ((3, 4), (3, 1), (2, 6)), ((3, 4), (3, 2), (1, 2)), ((3, 4), (3, 2), (2, 4)), ((3, 4), (3, 2), (2, 5)), ((3, 4), (3, 2), (2, 6))]
```

Comment: In this case, I need to geerate all permutions, but it is not what I want. It will take a lot of time when working with array of size 50.

Comment: `itertools.permutations` is a iterator, which means that it evaluates as we go along, and does not evaluate everything at once, hence it is fast

Comment: It is not good solution, no needed pairs are not skipped. All permutations are generated and testes. It will take a lot of time.

Comment: Not needed pairs are being skipped , can you show me in output which non needed pairs are not skipped? Also in terms of taking time, you  can always parallelize via threads etc, I am not sure you can avoid generating all combinations. Besides you can generate all possible combinations you need and persist them somewhere so as to not needing to generate them again